# Flutter FCM image not showing in notification

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

any tips on how to show the images I record in the firebase console in the push notification? They are working but when I send with an image it does not appear in the notification. I'm using firebase_message and flutter_local_notifications.

When I send the notification it appears, but the image does not. Remembering that the image I put the URl in the creation of the notification in the firebaseConsole

FirebaseConfiguration:

```
class FireBaseNotifications {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final LocalNotifications _localNotifications;

  FireBaseNotifications._internal(this._localNotifications);
  static final FireBaseNotifications _singleton =
      FireBaseNotifications._internal(LocalNotifications());
  factory FireBaseNotifications() => _singleton;

  Future<void> initializeFirebasePushServices() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
            badge: true, sound: true, alert: true);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (push) {
        RemoteNotification? notification = push.notification;
        AndroidNotification? androidNotification = push.notification?.android;
        AppleNotification? iosNotification = push.notification?.apple;

        if (notification != null && androidNotification != null) {
          _localNotifications.androidNotifications(
            notification: notification,
            androidNotification: androidNotification,
          );
        }
        if (notification != null && iosNotification != null) {
          _localNotifications.iosNotifications(
            notification: notification,
            iosNotification: iosNotification,
          );
        }
      },
    );
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(
        (route) {
          if (route.data['goTo'] != null) {
            navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(route.data['goTo']);
          }
        },
      );
    }
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(
        (route) {
          if (route.data['goTo'] != null) {
            navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(route.data['goTo']);
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> getTokenFirebase() async =>
      debugPrint(await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken());
}
```

Flutter local notifications:

```
class LocalNotifications {
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  late AndroidNotificationChannel androidNotificationChannel;
  LocalNotifications() {
    androidNotificationChannel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel',
      'high_importance_notifications',
      description: 'channel used for very important notifications',
      importance: Importance.max,
    );
    _androidConfig().then(
      (value) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = value;
        initializeNotifications();
      },
    );
    _iosConfig().then((value) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = value;
      initializeNotifications();
    });
  }

  Future<FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin> _androidConfig() async {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(androidNotificationChannel);
    return flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  }

  Future<FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin> _iosConfig() async {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    return flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  }

  void initializeNotifications() {
    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    const ios = IOSInitializationSettings(
      // onDidReceiveLocalNotification: ,
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestAlertPermission: false,
    );
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .initialize(const InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: ios));
  }

  void androidNotifications({
    required RemoteNotification notification,
    required AndroidNotification? androidNotification,
  }) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            androidNotificationChannel.id, androidNotificationChannel.name,
            channelDescription: androidNotificationChannel.description,
            icon: androidNotification?.smallIcon),
      ),
    );
  }

  void iosNotifications({
    required RemoteNotification notification,
    required AppleNotification? iosNotification,
  }) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      const NotificationDetails(
        iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: After adding the Notification Service Extension (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration), make sure the target iOS of the extension is lower than your device iOS version.

For example if you device iOS is 15.0, set the target version to 12.0.

In Xcode navigator click "Runner", under TARGETS select the new extension, under General tab go to Deployment info, change iOS target

Answer (score 0):

In the Firebase Console, ensure that the URL of the image or the uploaded image size is less than 1MB. This applies to both the image uploaded through the console and the image URL sent in the payload from the server. [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image)